# Inverted HashMap in Java whit frequency

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>>` and I want to create a `hashMapInverted<LinkedList<Integer>, Set<String>>` which contains in keys the lists, values of first map, and the values the set of strings which have the same list in first map.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you simply tried looping on the first map to populate the new map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Map<LinkedList<Integer>, Set<String>> mapInverted = new HashMap<>(myMap.size());
for(Entry<<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    LinkedList<Integer> list = entry.getValue();
    Set<String> strings = mapInverted.get(list);
    if(strings == null) { // the list has not already been put in the map
        strings = new HashSet<String>(); // create a new set
        mapInverted.put(list, strings); // put the list and the new set
    }
    strings.add(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
Map<String, LinkedList<Integer>> map =new HashMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>>();
Map<LinkedList<Integer>, Set<String>> invertMap = new HashMap<LinkedList<Integer>, Set<String>>();
for (Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(invertMap.containsKey(entry.getValue())){
        invertMap.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());
    }else{
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add(entry.getKey());
        invertMap.put(entry.getValue(), set);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the new map to be a `Map<LinkedList<Integer>, Set<String>>`.

Comment: `Map<V, K> invertMap = new HashMap<V, K>();` return map is whole new map.

Comment: Values in the initial map are not unique, so the values in the inverted map is a collection, not a single item. For the same reason a BiMap would not work... (At least that's what I understand the OP is saying)

Comment: @assylias Your understanding is 100% right and thank you very much for your comment. :)